# How to check if a String is a number or not

Tags: java, string, double

There not much to explain here, I need to check if a String is a number or not, I tried this recommended method, but sometimes fails:

```
try {

    Double.parseDouble((String) myString);
    // CODE IF IT IS A NUMBER HERE

} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    // CODE IF IT IS NOT A NUMBER HERE
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The string that makes it fail is `C:\Users\xx11\Desktop\Example\Example.doc`.

I think it has to do with `11\D` part, but I am not sure and I can´t prove it.

Does anyone with more experience have any idea why this is happening and how to fix it?

Thank you.

Comment: What is `C:\Users\xx11\Desktop\Excel\Excel.opc`? What is `11\D`?

Comment: When you `.parseDouble()`, _the whole string_ is expected to be a number!

Comment: What are `i`, `j`, `data`, `getData`, `get`?..

Comment: Yes your Double.parseDouble will fail if string your are parsing is not double type. For which you have already handled NumberFormatException. So what is the issue here?

Comment: Or you could use `matches("\\d+(\\.\\d+)?)"`

Comment: @TheLostMind no, not `.matches()`... The most misnamed method in Java if there is one... Also, `*`? That will match `1.2.3`

Comment: you could use ``org.apache.commons.lang.math.NumberUtils`` library. calling ``isNumber(number)`` method

Comment: What format do you expect in the string that it is considered as a number? If the string often could contain a non-number then you should avoid anything which throws an exception.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if a String is numeric in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102891/how-to-check-if-a-string-is-numeric-in-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Double.parseDouble()` is not the *recommended method*. Recommended by whom and for what? It uses the rules for `double` literals [in Java source code](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#valueOf(java.lang.String)), which 99% is not how you want your program to be fed (it allows exponents, hexadecimals and whatnot). Oh, and it's not locale sensitive.

If the input comes from a human you'd better use [`DecimalFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) that is locale-aware and can be easily customized (it even offers control over rounding mode):

```
DecimalFormat fmt = new DecimalFormat();
Number number = fmt.parse(input);
```

From a DecimalFormat you can get an Integer, a Number or a BigDecimal, depending on what that quantity describes and how you plan to use it.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. Tried this, `SimpleDecimalFormat` does not exist as a Java "Default" class.

Comment: Maybe `import java.text.DecimalFormat`?

Comment: Now that you edited the code, yes. Before, with `SimpleDecimalFormat`, didn´t work. :)

Answer (score 2):

Do not be distracted by secondary things. Use utilites for such tasks. For example *Apache Commons Lang*:

```
NumberUtils.isNumber(s);
```

What can be esear?

Comment: I don´t want to use external APIs, there are always problems with licences. But thank you for the suggestion though :)

Comment: @Mayuso there are lots of free library including **org.apache.commons.lang.math.NumberUtils**  and **org.apache.commons.lang.math.StringUtils**. another option ``StringUtils.isNumeric(arg0);``

Comment: It depends on the format what is considered/expected as number. If an integer is expected in the string `NumberUtils.isNumber(s)` would be simple overkill and `NumberUtils.isDigit(s)` should be prefered.

Comment: @Mayuso What problem do you have with the [_Apache License_](http://choosealicense.com/licenses/apache-2.0/)?

Comment: `Apache Commons Lang` is open source library. It is free for use, and thousands of developers use it to save time. It contains a lot of useful tools, although small in size. By the way, most of frameworks, that you will use, already apply this library.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose I don´t know about Apache Licence in particular, but most of these "Open Source" licenses make you have to release your project as Open Source too, and I am not interested in that, plus I have no time to read through 20+ different licences just for 2 (or 1) lines of code.

Comment: @Mayuso Well, the Apache license does not "make you have to release your project as Open Source too". I linked a page that explains that as short terms with colors on the right side. Check the [license overview page](http://choosealicense.com/licenses/) for other examples, especially the GNU license. And ... as a professional software developer, you _have to take the time_ and read licenses carefully.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose I am not a professional developer. Thank you anyways :)

Answer (score 0):

`Double.parseDouble()` will not try and find a number within an input for you. It expects the input as a whole to be a number. Same goes for `Integer.parseInt()` etc.

You need to extract what can possibly be a number *first*, then try and parse that. For instance:

```
private static final Pattern NUMERIC = Pattern.compile("\\d+(\\.\\d+)?");

// In code:

final Matcher m = NUMERIC.matcher(input);

while (m.find()) {
    // try and parse m.group())
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't he use `matches` instead of `find()`?

Comment: @TheLostMind no, precisely. The OP seems to want to find a number in a string. If you `.matches()`, the whole input is expected to be matched.

Comment: >  The OP seems to want to find a number in a string.    No, I want to know if a string is a number or not. If a string is "asd11asdn", it contains a number, but it is not a number. :)

Comment: @Mayuso But your example string "C:\Users\xx11\Desktop\Excel\Excel.opc" exactly is that: A string that only contains a number, but isn't one. And you explained that it fails to parse it.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose I am sorry, my english is not good enough. I meant that it makes my check fail (It does not throw exception, which I expect it to do it).